# Saber se um valor existe em um array

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array na variável `$menu`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'principal' => string 'regulacao' (length=9)
      'submenu' => string 'agenda' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'principal' => string 'regulacao' (length=9)
      'submenu' => string 'marcacao' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'principal' => string 'gestao' (length=6)
      'submenu' => string 'usuarios' (length=8)
```

Preciso saber se uma certa palavra existe, ex:

```
if (array_value_exists('regulacao')) //return true
if (array_value_exists('marcacao')) //return true
if (array_value_exists('usuarios')) //return true
if (array_value_exists('gestao')) //return true
```

Tentei usando `if (array_search('regulacao', $menu))` mas ele retorna `false`

Alguma dica?

Comment: Deve considerar tanto o valor em `principal` como em `submenu`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim

Comment: Uma dia: para perguntar prefira colocar o resultado de `var_export`, pois é mais fácil para copiarmos o *array* que está testando e ainda fica legível.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com a função abaixo:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle === $value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```